# How to find the query for creating a table in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to display the query for creating a table? For example, there is a table called CLIENT, and I want to see the query for creating this table. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

1. Right Click on the table
2. Script Table as
3. CREATE to
4. New Query Editor Window

[image]

EDIT: Damn you have to be quick here for the easy rep! haha.

Comment: Thanks Shiva! Just started on SO after being a leech for quite a few years.

Answer (score 1):

Right click the table in SSMS and select Script Table > As Create

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it from some script then here it is

```
declare @table varchar(100)
set @table = 'client_table' -- set table name here
declare @sql table(s varchar(1000), id int identity)

-- create statement
insert into  @sql(s) values ('create table [' + @table + '] (')

-- column list
insert into @sql(s)
select 
    '  ['+column_name+'] ' + 
    data_type + coalesce('('+cast(character_maximum_length as varchar)+')','') + ' ' +
    case when exists ( 
        select id from syscolumns
        where object_name(id)=@table
        and name=column_name
        and columnproperty(id,name,'IsIdentity') = 1 
    ) then
        'IDENTITY(' + 
        cast(ident_seed(@table) as varchar) + ',' + 
        cast(ident_incr(@table) as varchar) + ')'
    else ''
    end + ' ' +
    ( case when IS_NULLABLE = 'No' then 'NOT ' else '' end ) + 'NULL ' + 
    coalesce('DEFAULT '+COLUMN_DEFAULT,'') + ','

 from information_schema.columns where table_name = @table
 order by ordinal_position

-- primary key
declare @pkname varchar(100)
select @pkname = constraint_name from information_schema.table_constraints
where table_name = @table and constraint_type='PRIMARY KEY'

if ( @pkname is not null ) begin
    insert into @sql(s) values('  PRIMARY KEY (')
    insert into @sql(s)
        select '   ['+COLUMN_NAME+'],' from information_schema.key_column_usage
        where constraint_name = @pkname
        order by ordinal_position
    -- remove trailing comma
    update @sql set s=left(s,len(s)-1) where id=@@identity
    insert into @sql(s) values ('  )')
end
else begin
    -- remove trailing comma
    update @sql set s=left(s,len(s)-1) where id=@@identity
end

-- closing bracket
insert into @sql(s) values( ')' )

-- result!
select s from @sql order by id
```

this will give you the output like

```
create table [client_table] (
  [colA] varchar(250)  NOT NULL DEFAULT (''),
  [colB] int NOT NULL DEFAULT(0)
)
```